# GPUImage Blur exclude freeform area

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I want to blur a picture taken with the iPad camera. However I don't want to blur a specific area (denoted in red). I have looked at GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter. It is exactly the idea I am going for however I have a freeform area to exclude not a circle or ellipse. For example if a triangle is drawn the blur cannot be shaped in that way. I have done quite a bit of research into the problem but I can't seem to find a way to exclude the area and when I use Mask filter I am left with only the excluded area and a white background. The red polygon is a UIImage

```
    let blurFilter = GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter()
    blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 10.0

    let maskFilter = GPUImageMaskFilter()

    let maskGPUImage = GPUImagePicture(image: maskImg)

    let filterBgImage = GPUImagePicture(image: capturedImage)


    filterBgImage.addTarget(maskFilter)
    filterBgImage.processImage()

    maskFilter.useNextFrameForImageCapture()

    maskGPUImage.addTarget(maskFilter)
    maskGPUImage.processImage()

    session.image = maskFilter.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
```

[image: Simple example]

[image: Final Image after filtering]

Comment: Is there another way you can approach this? Composite two images together, the first being your original image with polygon cropped out and then blurred (leaving a hole in the middle), composited with the original image underneath? Seems like a more straightforward solution if there's no way to achieve your desired blur effect using masks.

Comment: I think that would work well! Do you have a suggestion to crop out the polygon area? A link if you would be so kind

Comment: Haha, I'm not much of an iOS developer, my comment was purely theoretical in nature. Hopefully it points you in the right direction and gives you some more things to google for.

Comment: oh alright thanks for the idea